# Dependent dropdowns in from an array in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, node.js

Lets I have an array of size and price some thing like this

```
array = [[large, 100],[medium, 70],[small, 50]]
```

I want two drop downs one for size and one for price. I want if user select large from first drop down the price 100 will be selected automatically and it needs to be disable. Its simple but I need help I am using rails 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Convert the array to a hash, grab the keys and values, and you will now have an array of `sizes` and an array of `prices`:

```
array = [['large', 100],['medium', 70],['small', 50]]
h = Hash[array]
sizes = h.keys
prices = h.values
```

These are your two select dropdowns for `sizes` and `prices`:

```
select_tag "Sizes", options_for_select(sizes)
select_tag "Prices", options_for_select(prices), disabled: true
```

And the following javascript will set the `price` based on what `size` is selected:

```
$(function() {
  var prices, sizes;
  sizes = $("#sizes");
  prices = $("#prices");
  return sizes.change(function() {
    if (sizes.val() === 'large') {
      prices.val('100');
    }
    if (sizes.val() === 'medium') {
      prices.val('70');
    }
    if (sizes.val() === 'small') {
      return prices.val('50');
    }
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.